# Problemas con Task Scheduling Laravel 6

Tags: laravel

Buen día, 
Estoy tratando de realizar una tarea programada en laravel y cpanel, en la cual me borra cada mes los registros temporales de unos folios en Mysql, pero no me esta funcionando eh visto muchas preguntas aquí y en la documentación oficial de larevel 6

¿Quizá alguien me pueda guiar en que estoy haciendo mal?

Mi Command

```
    <?php

namespace App\Console\Commands;

use Illuminate\Console\Command;

class TruncateTempFolios extends Command
{
    /**
     * The name and signature of the console command.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $signature = 'truncate:TempFolios';

    /**
     * The console command description.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $description = 'Borrar cada primero de mes la tabla temp_folios';
    /**
     * Create a new command instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    /**
     * Execute the console command.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        \DB::statement("SET foreign_key_checks=0");
        \DB::table('temporal_folios')->truncate();
        \DB::statement("SET foreign_key_checks=1");
    }
}
```

Mi Console/Kernel

```
<?php

namespace App\Console;

use Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel as ConsoleKernel;

class Kernel extends ConsoleKernel
{
    /**
     * The Artisan commands provided by your application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $commands = [
        Commands\TruncateTempFolios::class,
    ];

    /**
     * Define the application's command schedule.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule  $schedule
     * @return void
     */
    protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {
        $schedule->command('truncate:TempFolios')
        ->timezone('America/Tijuana')
        ->monthlyOn(1, '00:00');
    }

    /**
     * Register the commands for the application.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function commands()
    {
        $this->load(__DIR__.'/Commands');

        require base_path('routes/console.php');
    }
}
```

Tarea Cron en cpanel

0   0   1   *   *   /usr/local/bin/php /home/domain/public_html/test/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1

Hice algunas pruebas en local y funcionan algunos test de cada minuto pero en el hosting compartido no funcionan!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tal y como dice la documentación de Laravel, el cron debe ejecutarse cada minuto, lo cual se logra con la siguiente sintaxis:

```
* * * * * /usr/local/bin/php /home/domain/public_html/test/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

Todo esto, asumiendo que la ruta de php y de artisan son correctas.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/scheduling#introduction

Comment: Listo esto era @Shaz gracias